# Copying between different sized buffers that are templated by their fixed size

Tags: c++, templates

The simplified version would be something like this:

```
template<int Size> struct IntBuffer {int items[Size];}

IntBuffer<32> b1;
IntBuffer<16> b2;


b1 = b2; // I want this to be allowed as the size of b1 >= b2
b2 = b1; // I want this to be disallowed as the size of b2 < b1
```

EDIT: Seems I should be more clear... I want to cause a compile time error if the assignment is disallowed due to the size constraint behaviour mentioned.  Also without boost and ideally friendly to compilers that might not have full C++11 support like MSVC 2010.

Comment: Implement copy constructor/overloaded assignment operator and apply your logic inside.

Comment: Add an assignment operator template with a `static_assert` inside (requires C++11 support).

Comment: I wonder why these comments are no answers...

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned ideally something that is friendly pre full C++11 support

Comment: `static_assert` is supported in VS2010.

Comment: @dyp: That's interesting I didn't realise that... but still without that support it was useful to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to overload the assignment operator with a template which has the size of the other buffer as a parameter. In the implementation, you can `static_assert` your requirement if you can use C++11:

```
template<int OtherSize>
IntBuffer<Size> & operator=(const IntBuffer<OtherSize> & other) {
    static_assert(OtherSize <= Size, "Error assigning to IntBuffers of different size: The size of the right hand side buffer shouldn't be larger than the one on the left hand side.");
    // (implementation)
}
```

If you can't use **that feature** of C++11 (you don't need **full** C++11) due to compiler limitations, you can also use a SFINAE-based approach, but you can't emit descriptive error messages in this case:

```
template<int OtherSize>
typename enable_if<OtherSize <= Size, IntBuffer<Size> &>::type
//                 ^---------------^  ^---------------^
//                    requirement        return type
operator=(const IntBuffer<OtherSize> &other) {
    // (implementation)
}
```

where `enable_if` is simply a copy of a possible implementation of `std::enable_if` if you use pre-C++11:

```
template<bool B, class T = void>
struct enable_if {};

template<class T>
struct enable_if<true, T> { typedef T type; };
```

(source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if)

**Demo: http://ideone.com/uXGo5E**

Comment: It's the SFINAE approach that my brain is failing me on - I updated the question to mention ideally pre-C++11 support - my bad for not mentioning that.

Comment: You can simulate static_assert pre-C++11 by specializing a template that takes a bool.

Comment: Ah ok I think I understand now from that... thank you.

Comment: @leemes: I am pretty sure I should mark that the answer thanks... just going through it with the coffee...

Comment: I need stronger coffee as it took me a moment to realise that I think the condition is the wrong way around in your example.  I think it should be: enable_if<OtherSize <= Size...

Comment: @wb. Yeah I edited it just a moment after posting the code :) Sorry for confusing you.

Answer (score 2):

First let me say that it doesn't seem intuitive to me that you should do this. If I'm a reading of the code and see that, I'm going to wonder what happened to the OTHER elements if the destination buffer size is bigger than the source buffer size (will they be retained? Will they be cleared? Will they be changed in some other non-deterministic way?). Not only that, but if you restrict it to same-sized buffers, the compiler generated copy constructor and copy assignment operator will just WORK, no extra work required on your part.

But if after all that you *still* want to do it, you can create your own copy assignment operator. You'll have to write your own `static_assert` (but you certainly *can* do that in C++98 since boost has done it) since you've explicitly excluded the two places I know to get one that's already written and debugged for you (C++11 and boost).

The operator might look something like this:

```
template <int Size> template <int RightSize>
IntBuffer<Size>& IntBuffer<Size>::operator=(const IntBuffer<RightSize>& right)
{
    static_assert(RightSize <= Size);
    // The real work.
}
```

Comment: This is the right answer if I hadn't been after understanding how you can do it pre-C++11.  But that was my fault for not specifying that at the start sorry!  Regards the actual use case it's a little bit more complicated so it's not as bad as you fear ;-)

Comment: Why is your operator templated twice? (It looks like an in-class implementation to me, where the first template should not be there.)

Comment: Should be template <int Size, int RightSize> I guess just a typo?

Comment: @wb. No the `Size` is a parameter of the class template. As soon as the class template is instantiated, `Size` is fixed and thus not a template parameter *anymore* for the actual operator. Only if you implement the functions outside of the class template, you need to add the class' template parameters *in addition* to the function's template parameters, hence the double template. But then, the `IntBuffer<Size>::` is missing in the code snippet.

Comment: @wb No, it's a template assignment operator of a template class, I just left off `IntBuffer<Size>::` accidentally there. Thanks @leemes for pointing out my mistake.